# Find all functions with given property (differential-equations?)

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Find all functions $f$ such that $[f(x)]^2= \frac{1}{x} \int_{x}^{1} f(t)dt$ when $x>0$

What should I do to find the answer?

EDIT:
I tried to derivate this and got $2(x)f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}f(x)+\frac{1}{x}f(x)$ assuming that $f(1)=0$ Is that somehow correct?

and then i solved differential equation and got $y=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{x}+ln|x|)+c$ and where $c=-\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous then $F(x)=\int_1^x f(t)dt$ is an antiderivative of $f$ with $F(1)=0$

So you might rewrite your equation as:

$x\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\right)^2=-F(x)$, with boundary condition $F(1)=0$

The last one is a separable differential equation. with the non-trivial solution

$F(x)=-(\sqrt x - 1)^2$. so

$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt x}-1$

If continuity of $f$ is not assumed, you might still be able to infer it from the original equation. $F$ is continuous from its integral definition, from where you get $f^2$ and |f| continuous but I  don't see at the first sight how to prove that $f$ is continuous.

EDIT: After more thinking, if you change the sign of an individual value of $f$ in one point (or more general, on a set of Lebesgue measure zero), the equation still holds so the continuity of $f$ cannot be inferred from the equation. But at least this solution does not assume $f$ differentiable.

Comment: ok, thanks. I did it your way and got two solutions $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt x}-1$ and $f(x)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt x}-1$ could you explain why $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{x}+ln|x|)-\frac{1}{2}$ is wrong?

Comment: If you plug the last function into the original equation you get on the LHS something like $\left(\frac{1-x+x\ln x}{2x}\right)^2$ and on the RHS something like $1-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\ln x}{2x}-\frac{1}{2}\ln x$ Does it seem to you that LHS=RHS? Try to graph LHS and RHS.

Comment: Also $f(x)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt x}-1$ does not satisfy $f(1)=0$

Answer (score 1):

What I did, is that I supposed the function to be differentiable and differentiated both sides. So I takes form $$2f(x)f'(x) = -\frac{f(x)}{x}-\frac{1}{x^{2}}\int_{x}^{1}f(t)dt = -\frac{f(x)}{x}-\frac{1}{x}f^{2}(x)$$.

See that $f(x)=0$, is solution. For the other cases, there it at least one point for which we can write
$$2f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x}(f(x)+1)$$.

This is just an ordinary differential equation.

My solution is really incomplete. I'm sorry.

Comment: $-\frac{1}{x^{2}}\int_{x}^{1}f(t)dt = -\frac{1}{x}f^{2}(x)$ how did you get that? Thanks for help

Comment: No. I just did like this $(f(x)g(x))' = f'(x)g(x)+ f(x)g'(x)$ and $\left(\int_{x}^{a}f(t)dt \right)' = -f(x)$

Comment: A ok, I understood you wrong. That's because of the initial condition.(I mean the equation we are solving)) .)